# Поиск по исходному коду страницы

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Начал разбираться с JavaScript для GreaseMonkey. Возник вопрос: как делать поиск какого-нибудь выражения по исходному коду страницы?
Затем еще парочка вопросов:
1) запомнить в переменную какую-то часть вокруг найденного.
2) Можно ли это сделать проще? (не поиск на совпадение текста.)

Пример того, что имею в виду. Пусть есть исходный код(точнее, его часть):

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<tr><td></td><td align=center><font color=silver>вверх</font></td><td><font color=silver>север</font></td></tr>
<tr><td align=right><font color=silver>запад</font></td><td align=center valign=middle><img src="../design/dimension-9.gif" width=60 height=55 border=0 hspace=0 vspace=0></td><td><font color=silver>восток</font></td></tr>
<tr><td align=right><a href="/example/?c=3&b=ad449bf">юг</a></td><td align=center><font color=silver>вниз</font></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Требуется запомнить в переменную следующее: `/example/?c=3&b=ad449bf`, стоящее перед >юг

Comment: Если код стабилен, проще посмотреть где расположены ключевые элементы и их искать через селекторы. А если код **не** стабилен, то регулярки не спасут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бота на текстовую игру пишите?) Такое подойдет?

```
var url = document.querySelector('table').innerHTML.match(/href="([^"]+)"\>юг/)[1];
```

Или:

```
var url = document.body.innerHTML.match(/href="([^"]+)"\>юг/)[1];
```

Не забудьте это все проверять обработчике событий `onload` или `onDOMContentLoaded`, чтобы данные успели загрузиться.

Comment: a для чего нужен `[1]` в конце строки?

Comment: Скобками в регулярном выражении задается `Capturing group`, `match()` - отдает массив, где, начиная с индекса `[1]`, записывается содержимое соответствующее регулярному выражению в скобках.

Comment: А под индексом `[0]` - undefined? А во всех последующих индексах - все другие совпадения по этому регулярному выражению?

Comment: Нет, под индексом `0` лежит строка подходящее под все регулярное выражение. Если ничего не нашлось то `.match()` вернет `null`.